# Check if variable is greater than something but not undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement

```
var ship = $("input[name=shippingamt]").length;
var counting1 = $(".submit-btn-1 li.checked:not(.title)").length;

if ((counting1 == 6)&&(ship >= 1)&&($('input[name=ideclare1]').is(":checked"))){
```

The above snippet is what I have so far, pretty much I have a 3 essential fields, a variable called **Ship**, an checklist called **counting1** and a checkbox check.

But if **Ship** and **Checklist** are fine and the checkbox called **ideclare1** is checked and unchecked then the value **ship** goes to undefined and is still class as valid as the length is **>= 1**.

Can any suggest how to check if a field is defined and has a length greater than 1?

Regards,

Donald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `.length` of the jQuery object.

```
var ideclare = $('input[name=ideclare1]');

if ((counting1 == 6)&&(ship >= 1)&&(ideclare.length > 0 && ideclare.is(":checked"))){
```

*edit* well if  you're just checking a regular variable, just compare it to `undefined`:

```
if (counting1 == 6 && (ship !== undefined && ship >= 1) ...
```

Comment: Sorry @Pointy Its the variable ship I need to check is >= 1 && is not undefined

Comment: Don't need to check for undefined before doing the >= 1. If ship is undefined it is also not greater or equal than 1 (undefined >= 1) === false

Comment: @BartRiemens yes that's true but it's not a terrible thing to check; the number on the right might change someday.

Comment: Trying some similar condition, but can't get it work. `if (a > b && c !== undefined && a < c) {}`. `a` and `b` are declared, c not. When c isn't undefined, I would like to have the condition a > b and a < c. If c is undefined the condition should be a > b only. What am I missing? The last line of you're is not valid. I think that there will be the problem for me. @Pointy

Comment: @Caspert you need to check `c` *first* then to determine the subsequent comparisons to make.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Like so `if (c !== undefined && a > b && a < c) {}` or another way? @Pointy

Comment: Well I guess `if (a > b && (c === undefined || a < c))` would work.

Comment: Yes. That's the right syntax. Thank you so much! :)